# REST Web Service 404 Not found - ColdFusion 11

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I created a new function in an existing REST cfc but when I am trying to call it I receive a 404 Error where the rest of the functions are working. All of the functions are following the same structure as the one I am about to link further down without any issues.

I saw another post like mine but I didn't find any answers in it. This is the link for the other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446919/rest-404-not-found)

```
<cfcomponent restpath="student" rest="true">
<cffunction name="npssummary" access="remote" output="false" returntype="any" httpmethod="get" restpath="npssummary" produces="application/json">   

        <cfquery name="nps_summary" datasource="dpsigweb2">
            select top 10 * from contact
        </cfquery>

        <cfreturn serializeJSON(nps_summary,"struct")>

  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

And this is how I am calling it

```
<cfhttp url="http://dev.example.com/rest/IIT/student/npssummary" method="get">
<cfset results = "#cfhttp#">
<cfdump var="#results#">
```

When I am trying to call the function directly in the browser I receive the expected result.

Also, I am using this function to reset the REST services each time I make a change to my component it seems to be working as expected so far.

```
<cftry>
<cfset restInitApplication("Z:\Sites\testSites\API\","IIT")>

<cfcatch type="any">
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: Can you post an entire CFC, holding one method that DOES work, and one that doesn't? Also how you call each of them.

Comment: I will change my functions and post all of the cfc

Comment: Cheers. Just enough to repro the situation yeah, not tonnes and tonnes of code.

Comment: I think I just found my issue... The params that I was sending to the method were too big... is there such a thing? `<cfhttpparam type="URL" name="DoctorIDs" value="2008013110482896439177,2010080209524690985587,2003051416543440840952">` But imagine it having about a 100 more IDs @AdamCameron

Comment: Well that's easy enough to test/(dis)prove. I would not expect a string that long to give you a problem, that said. And if it did, I'd not expect a 404.

Comment: I removed a 'few' ID from my params going in the function and it worked

Comment: @AdamCameron After a couple of tests it seems like the size of my parameters are causing the issue. Is there another variable besides the URL type that can support a longer string?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I'll rally the troops to see if anyone else knows...

Comment: If you are sending that much over the wire, in a url... you might need to consider a new endpoint, that can support a POST.
URLs can only support about 2000 characters give or take.
So if you post instead of get, it should work. But if you have TRUE rest endpoints, and a post will call another handler, then you'll need another ENDPOINT so it doesn't conflict.

Comment: @GavinPickin your method kinda makes sense, do you have a link where I can go and read more about these kind of limitations?

Answer (score 1):

[This is a browser limitation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427):

> Microsoft Internet Explorer has a maximum uniform resource locator (URL) length of 2,083 characters. Internet Explorer also has a maximum path length of 2,048 characters. This limit applies to both POST request and GET request URLs.
>
> If you are using the GET method, you are limited to a maximum of 2,048 characters, minus the number of characters in the actual path.
>
> However, the POST method is not limited by the size of the URL for submitting name/value pairs. These pairs are transferred in the header and not in the URL.
>
> RFC 2616, "Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1," does not specify any requirement for URL length.