# ColdFusion REST 404

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I'm setting up a ColdFusion 2016 RESTful web services, but keep getting a 404 Error. 1st step, I registered a rest service via CF admin.

C:\users\dev_2\ColdFusion Builder 2016 workspacce\svn\restful and called it IIT.

Now, I have C:\users\dev_2\ColdFusion Builder 2016 workspacce\svn\restful\restTest.cfc which is:

```
<cfcomponent restpath="restTest" rest="true" >
<!--- handle GET request (httpmethod), take argument in restpath(restpath={customerID}), return query data in json format(produces=text/json) ---> 
<cffunction name="getHandlerJSON" access="remote" httpmethod="GET" restpath="{customerID}" returntype="query" produces="application/json"> 
    <cfargument name="customerID" required="true" restargsource="Path" type="numeric"> 
    <cfset myQuery = queryNew("id,name", "Integer,varchar", [[1, "Sagar"], [2, "Ganatra"]])> 
    <cfquery dbtype="query" name="resultQuery"> 
        select * from myQuery 
        where id = #arguments.customerID# 
    </cfquery> 
    <cfreturn resultQuery> 
</cffunction> 
</cfcomponent>
```

I also created C:\users\dev_2\ColdFusion Builder 2016 workspacce\svn\restful\Test.cfm which has the following:

```
<cfhttp url="https://local.mydomain.com/rest/IIT/restTest/1" method="get" result="res">   
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json">
```

When I run Test.cfm, I am getting 404 Not Found. What am I missing here? I'm following the response from this link
[REST - 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446919/rest-404-not-found) but no dice. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3):

The root cause was because coldfusion requires mapping for the rest API directory prior to setting up the rest service.